# Pass image from one view controller to another controller gives nil

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am trying to send an image to the **preview controller** as shown below. My issue is that in the **preview controller** `newImage` is `nil`

Below is the code:

**FirstViewController**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("In here")
    if segue.identifier == "showImage" {

        let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "showImage") as! showImageController

        secondViewController.newImage =  UIImage(named: imageArray[0])

    }
}
```

**PreviewController**

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageHolder: UIImageView!
var newImage: UIImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageHolder.image = newImage
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `segue.destination` not create a new one , like this

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

   print("In here")

   if segue.identifier == "showImage" {

        let next = segue.destination as! showImageController

        next.newImage =  UIImage(named: imageArray[0])

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

instantiateViewController calls viewDidLoad() so you will not have setup your image when it gets called. Move the code to viewWillAppear() and it will work